# Cannot deactivate contact triggers (managed package) and because of that Update commands are failing

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, deactivate

I couldnt found good answer for that i cant change Active status in Setup->Contact->Trigger Mailchimp Trigger Like This [image]

if you cant see Look here = https://pasteboard.co/Ip9eoR8.png

I want to make deactive but i couldnt see anything i dont want to uninstall

Comment: sorry i cannot found this question because my question about 'How can i do deactive ready trigger on salesforce' and i ask clear question i cant update now in my apex code like this: https://pasteboard.co/Ip9qXyP.png  ---MC4SF  so mailchimp trigger working but i cant change settings

Comment: For example two: https://pasteboard.co/Ip9sWvA.png

Comment: and i couldnt found seems like this question : https://pasteboard.co/Ip9ucPz.png